# Convert array of objects into object

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

Trying to work with Mapael Jquery plugin.
Plugin need object to draw a map elements.

My PHP code return json encoded array of objects:

```
[{
    "Aveiro":{
        "latitude":40.6443,
        "longitude":-8.6455,
        "value":10,
        "tooltip":{
            "content":"test"
         }
    }
 },{
    "Lisbon":{
        "latitude":38.7167,
        "longitude":-9.1333,
        "value":10,
        "tooltip":{
            "content":"test"
        }
    }
 },{
    "Entroncamento":{
        "latitude":39.2333,
        "longitude":-9.0833,
        "value":10,
        "tooltip":{
            "content":"test"
        }
    }
 }]
```

If I parse this array thru `json.parse` I will receive object with numeric keys, in my example `[0]->[Aveiro],[1]->[Lisbon],[2]->[Entroncamento]`.

How it possible to have object with keys `[Aveiro],[Lisbon],[Entroncamento]` without array indexes?

If I return only one object - I receive object with named key and everything works just fine.

Comment: you have access to edit the php code? if so then share the code which builds that array

Comment: @metamarket I think you are looking for `$array =  (array) $yourObject;`. That will give you associative array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `reduce` the array given by `JSON.parse` to a single object:

```
var result = parsed.reduce(function (output, value) {
    return $.extend(output, value);
}, {});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ps1e9dyz/2/)